# JQuery: загрузка и обработка изображения

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, php

Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин jquery, который бы делал примерно так:
Сначала пользователь бы указывал картинку на своём компьютере, после того как указал она бы загрузилась уменьшенная до опр. размера, + вывелась в блок div а там её можно было бы обрезать. Ну и чтобы ссылка на фото отправлялась обработчику формы. Если нет такого чудо плагина, то хотябы подскажите по частям: например плагин загрузки и уменьшения и плагин обрезки ajax. А я их уж соединю) Подскажите, пож-та

Comment: Нет, такого в природе пока не существует. Зато есть варианты на flash и java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой механизм должен быть двухэтапным.
Первый этап - загрузка изображения на сервер.
Второй - вывод загруженного изображения в DOM, визуальная обработка (читай подготовка инструкций по обработке для сервера), и отправка этих инструкций.

К сожалению (или к счастью), такой вариант:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        alert( $(this).attr('value') );
    });
});
```

выведет `"C:\fakepath\Мое фото.jpg"`. Имя файла настоящее, а путь к нему - нет. И локально его загрузить в `<img />` не получится.

Comment: Сделал ajaxSubmit`ом, но он не работает в гугл-хроме, как минимум. Вообще удивляюсь, в мозиле всегда всё работает, а в другие даже боюсь лазить... Что-то наподобие ajaxSubmit есть кроссобраузерное?

Comment: Для jQuery есть плагины [Ajax File Upload][1] и [One Click Upload][2]

  [1]: http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/
  [2]: http://www.michaelmitchell.co.nz/one-click-upload/

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую

Comment: $.ajaxSubmit прекрасно работает во всех браузерах...

Comment: Ну пример же не работал в гугл хроме, а пример Ajax File Upload работает

Comment: Ах, нет, ошибаюсь, пример работает, там просто куда-то делась подключаемая jquery билиотека. Значит я что-то не так делаю( В каких случаях может return false не срабатывать, при чём не во всех браузерах?

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написал [@ling](/users/1252/ling) плагина нет.

Т.к. чтобы обработать картинку её нужно загрузить на сервак, потом её можно вывести в div там манипулировать на JS. потом то что в div загрузить вместо той которая была в оригинале.

Answer (score 0):

Да, плагина не нашёл, пришлось делать самому( Но там ничего трудного, не понимаю почему не сделали такой плагин...

Comment: Ну так сделай =)

Comment: И сделал (смайлик_языка)

Comment: @mctrane, можеть поделитесь )))